# How to use .each jQuery to set the IDs of my element with the attribute of another element

Tags: jquery, each

I have a web page with a name attribute to the caption tags. I want to be able to set the ids of each table with the name attribute of the caption.

Before :

```
<table>
<caption name="director">
...

<table>
<caption name="agent">
...
```

After :

```
<table id="director">
<caption name="director">
...

<table id="agent">
<caption name="agent">
...
```

So far, I have this jQuery to get the attribute's name and try to set the ids:

```
$('caption').each(function() {
    $getNameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
    $('table').attr('id',$getNameAttr);  
});
```

But it doesn't work to set it as the id of the tables.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the `caption` elements *within* or *after* the `table`? Also, this seems a little redundant when DOM traversal would be a better solution.

Comment: `$(this).closest("table").attr("id", $getNameAttr);`

Answer (score 1):

Can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to loop over all the tables and pull the id from instance specific caption element

```
$('table').attr('id', function(){
   return $(this).find('caption').attr('name')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to get the first table parent of your `captions` tag like the following:

```
$('caption').each(function() {
    $getNameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).closest('table').attr('id',$getNameAttr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead id, Id should be unique in a page.

```
  $('table').attr('id', function(){
       return $(this).find('caption').attr('name')
    })
```

Comment: Where do you use class in your answer?